# Angular Directive populated by api

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

Why when I use  this directive does not work. when I use only select works perfectly?

DOES NOT WORK

```
app.directive('selectMaritalStatus', function (PersonApi) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            return '<div class="nice-select">'+
                        '<select class="form-control" ng-options="value for (key, value) in maritalStatus">'+
                            '<option value="">Selecione um Estado Civil</option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                    '</div>';
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.loadSelect = function () {
                PersonApi.getMaritalStatus(function (data, result) {
                    var status = [];
                    for (var key in data.maritalStatus) {
                        status.push(data.maritalStatus[key]);
                    }
                    $scope.maritalStatus = status;

                });
            };
        },
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.maritalStatus = {};
            $scope.loadSelect();
        }
    };
});
```

WORKS

```
        return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.loadSelect = function () {
                PersonApi.getMaritalStatus(function (data, result) {
                    var status = [];
                    for (var key in data.maritalStatus) {
                        status.push(data.maritalStatus[key]);
                    }
                    $scope.maritalStatus = status;

                });
            };
        },
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.maritalStatus = {};
            $scope.loadSelect();
        },
        template: '<select class="form-control" ng-options="value for (key, value) in maritalStatus"><option value="">Selecione um Estado Civil</option></select>'

    };
```

I cannot understand why it does not work with a div covering the select. And this only works with replace true

Comment: try putting your template into an external .html file and using templateUrl: ? see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @EliteOctagon do not worked. The select is not populated. It only works with replace: true and without the first div